# case..when for a list of potential ancestors?

Tags: ruby

If I want to use a `case..when` to switch based on the kind of an object instance, I can simply do:

```
case obj
  when Class1
    "whatever"
  when Class2
    "something else"
end
```

But if the value I'm comparing is a class itself, and I want to switch based on the class it descends from, does `case..when` still hold up?  The following doesn't work, but does anything?

```
class Foo < String; end
class Bar < Array; end

klass = Foo

case klass
  when String
    "klass descends from String"
  when Array
    "klass descends from Array"
end
```

Basically what the `<=` operator does, but in the context of a `case..when`.

EDIT | Just to clarify, I want to support matching anywhere in the inheritance chain, not just the immediate parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
case
  when klass <= String
    "klass descends from String"
  when klass <= Array
    "klass descends from Array"
end
```

I'm not sure if it's any better than a bunch of if and elsif's though.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but isn't exactly pretty:

```
result = case
  when klass.ancestors.include?(String)
    "klass descends from String"
  when klass.ancestors.include?(Array)
    "klass descends from Array"
end
```

Comment: Yeah, these are basically just `if..else`, I guess. It's sort of like using the forbidden `switch(true) { case value < 7: ...; case value < 10: ...; }` in a C/Java-like language :)